# add a link in a symfony form

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I would like to add a link in my login form (password forgotten).

How can I add the link in the controller class. For now I have this :

```
$formBuilder = $this->createFormBuilder($defaultData, $defaultOptions);
$formBuilder->add('username', 'text', array(
                'required' => true 
            ))
            ->add('password', 'password', array(
                'required' => true
            ))
```

Do I have a create a special type? If yes, how do I do that?

Thank you

in the twig :

```
myFunction('formulaire',  {
            form: formLogin,
            required: true
        }),
```

Note : I may not touch the macros

Comment: How do you output this form?

Comment: in a twig, using special twig macros created by some other services.. I add an example

Comment: And how function `formulaire` works? Show code.

Comment: the question is more how do I pass a link in the form using the builder

Comment: OK, Do you want to pass link text and url from controller? Through `$defaultOptions`?

Comment: How do I generate a <a > link in the form through the builder.. is that possible ?

Comment: You can generate it in template. That is why I asked you how function formulaire works.

Comment: I cannot touch this function... My question concerns the builder in the controller. Is it possible to add a field of link type though it is not really a form field

Comment: You need to modify form template to show this link. Only adding or modifing forn type will not help.

Answer (score 2):

You can add it directly in your template with the "path()" function.

Exemple : `<a href="{{ path('name_of_your_password_forgotten_route') }}">Password forgotten ?</a>`

Comment: sorry.. it has to be in the controller class.. in the builder

Comment: You could generate the URL in your controller, then pass it to your FormType as an argument like:
`$url = $this->generateUrl('forgotten_password_route');
$form = $this->createForm(new LoginType($url );`

Then implement `__construct($url)` in your FormType.